# "Failed to execute child process (no such file or directory)"

Tags: linux, bash, parent-child, child-process

I am trying to bind a command to run a script to some key in openbox WM.I did that with the following xml lines:

```
.
.
<keybind key="W-t">
  <action name="Execute">
    <command>"bash /home/bibek/test.sh"</command>
  </action>
</keybind>
.
```

When I try to invoke the command using the key combination I so assigned, I get a pop-up with the error message:

```
Failed to execute child process "bash /home/bibek/test.sh" (no such file or directory)
```

This is what `~/test.sh` looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
audacious & exit`
```

I wish to be able to do more things obviously; it's a test script.
The script runs as expected from terminal. 
What might be the problem here?

Comment: So most likely `bash` cannot be found. Probably because the `PATH` environment variable does not contain what you expect. So try to answer this question: what _does_ that variable contain?

Comment: not found? I don't get it. I tried with different shebang (#!/bin/bash) too, for what it's worth.

Comment: No, this is the original command that cannot be found. You call: `bash ...` It is _that_ bash the system cannot find. It has nothing to do with the content of that file you then want to execute.

Comment: That's probably right, I will confirm if that really is the problem.

Comment: Could you edit your question to show how you've bound this command to a key in openbox?

Comment: My guess would be that the command cannot take any parameters.  Lucky for you, you don't need to, either.  Just leave off the `bash` -- the shebang line in the script will find the right interpreter, and is the more correct way to run the script anyway.

Comment: @tripleee that was the trick. Thanks. This is the first time I've seen this depth in unix. Clearly, I wasn't aware of the correct way to run script.

Comment: Maybe post that as an answer and accept it yourself then, so that this question no longer comes up as unanswered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This gets resolved by removing the `bash` while binding the key in openbox.   The openbox process runs the script and the shebang provided in the script invokes the corresponding interpreter itself.

Answer (score 2):

First make sure that both `bash` and your script have the correct path.

```
$ which bash
$ ls /home/bibek/test.sh
```

The path returned from `which bash` should be in your shebang and/or in the script in openbox wm. If you get 'command not found', then you need fix your $PATH variable.

Comment: `$ which bash` gives me `/bin/bash`. I tried using that shebang. Same result. Also tried using `/bin/bash ~/test.sh` in openbox instead of `bash ~/test.sh`, doesn't work either.

Comment: Using `~` will only work for `bibek`. For any other user, it will point to their own home directory. What does the script in openbox WM look like? You may want to debug there. See if you can get a simple `ls` command or something like that to run from openbox.

Comment: I am aware of that. Openbox is windows manager and uses xml in configuration file wherein I added a line to bind key "Win-t" to the command above.   `<keybind key="W-t"><action name="Execute"><command>"bash /home/bibek/test.sh"</command></action></keybind>` is the line. If I put `audacious` command, which is what's in the test.sh file, inside that command tag, it works as expected.

Comment: Try putting the full path to `bash` in the xml. -> `<command>"/bin/bash /home/bibek/test.sh"</command>`. Or did you already try this?

Comment: Same result. Strangely enough, though `$ /bin/bash /home/bibek/test.sh` works, the same command from "Alt+f2" run menu doesn't.

Comment: Call an exorcist. (Sorry I don't know anything about openbox)

Comment: try it with "/bin/bash -c /home/bibek/test.sh"

Comment: No, better to make your own script. Easier to add comments and you won't have to restart Openbox every time it changes.

Answer (score 0):

First line should be `#!/usr/bin`, not `#!/usr/bin/`. That `/` is also a problem.